# Angular CanDeactivate is not triggered when there are query parameters in the route

Tags: angular

I have two child modules, I need to display a confirmation on browser refresh on the product route. I have added canDeactivate and using at product module level.
canDeactivate  triggers fine when I do refresh on the route like http://example.com/product, but is not triggered where there a query parameter in the route like http://example.com/product?id=1
Can you please help figuring out the issue?

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'main',
        loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule),
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'product',
        loadChildren: () => import('./product/product-creation.module').then(m => m.ProductCreationModule),
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }

];
```

product module route

```
export const PRODUCT_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ProductComponent,
        canDeactivate: [ProductConfirmGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    }
];
```

CanDeactivate Guard

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductConfirmGuard implements CanDeactivate<ProductComponent> {
    canDeactivate(
        component: ProductComponent,
        currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
        nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot
    ): boolean | UrlTree | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
         if (!component.canDeactivate()) {
          return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on this, but wildcard `**` route should solve this. If not look for other options but the problem is, that quard `ProductConfirmGuard` is only activating on parent route `''` because you've said so on `PRODUCT_ROUTES`.

```js
export const PRODUCT_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '**',
        component: ProductComponent,
        canDeactivate: [ProductConfirmGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
    }
];
```

Comment: No, that did not fix